# selenium exception when trying to fetch string by element

Tags: java, selenium

I am using selenium 2.33 (eclipse) and I'm trying to fetch a string (few words) from a website by one of the following options:

```
vendorTitle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='Result_1']/strong[2]")).getText();
```

OR

```
vendorTitle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='Result_1']")).getText();
```

OR

```
vendorTitle = driver.findElement(By.id("Result_1")).getText();
```

But getting the following Exception:

> ERROR:org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@id='Result_1']"}
>   Command duration or timeout: 16 milliseconds
>   For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
>   Build info: version: '2.33.0', revision: '4ecaf82108b2a6cc6f006aae81961236eba93358', time: '2013-05-22 12:00:17'
>   System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_38'
>   Session ID: 15fff09c-3758-479e-bd5c-da15b13c8fd4
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
>   Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=21.0, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true}]

Have I done something wrong?

(I gathered the element "//a[@id='Result_1']/strong[2]" by the selenium IDE)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you wait for the element to be displayed?

Comment: Have you opened the page before trying to locate the element? I mean, did you execute something like `driver.get("http://yourpage.com");` before `driver.findElement(...)`?

Comment: I don't wait. I use driver.get(url); searching for a texton the page and then trying to fetch the element's text as mentioned.

Comment: Guys, thanks. it was really stupid by me. it caused due to some problematic command between the 'get' and the 'findElement'. thanks a lot!

Comment: Try waiting for the element before getting the text. Try something like this: `element = new WebDriverWait(driver, waitForTimeoutInSeconds()).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by));`

Answer (score 0):

Use below command

```
vendorTitle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='Result_1']").getAttribute("title")));
```

You will get the data based on `getAttribute`.

Comment: You don't know how the markup looks, so this is just guessing. It's best not to answer those questions at all and concentrate more on good questions.